# MVC error in BundleConfig class: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error, bundle

My **MVC** website has an `Runtime Error` on starting in `BundleConfig` class with the following title:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

[image]

**Usings:**

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
using BundleTransformer.Core.Bundles;
using BundleTransformer.Core.Orderers;
using BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers;
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   BundleTransformer.Core.BundleTransformerContext..ctor() +162
   BundleTransformer.Core.BundleTransformerContext.<.cctor>b__0() +44
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +416
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   BundleTransformer.Core.BundleTransformerContext.get_Current() +60
   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.CssTransformer..ctor(IMinifier minifier, IList`1 translators, IList`1 postProcessors, String[] ignorePatterns) +79
   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.CssTransformer..ctor() +97
   NWebsite.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\N\Web\N.Website\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:18
   NWebsite.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\N\Web\N.Website\Global.asax.cs:20

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9916613
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930508
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

**And MvcApplication class in Global.asax file:**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

What is it's reasons and how can i solve it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @IvanL, I didn't get any answer here and i don't remember what was my solution but try this: **1)** Backup you project **2)** Remove all bootstrap files from your project include `js`, `css`,... then build **3)** Run, is it work? **4)** Add last version of bootstrap to your project by `NuGet Package Manager`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to resolve this. It appears to occur when you are missing the right configuration in your web.config (in my case this occurred due to a missing web config transform for the given environment). So make sure the following is present in your web.config:

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <css>
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" />
    </translators>
    <postProcessors>
      <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
    </postProcessors>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
      <add fileExtension=".less" assetTypeCode="Less" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </css>
  <js>
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
    </translators>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </js>
</core>
<less>
  <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
</less>
</bundleTransformer>
<jsEngineSwitcher xmlns="http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <engines>
    <add name="MsieJsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
  </engines>
</core>
</jsEngineSwitcher>
```

Comment: I could not test your answer myself but i mark it as accepted answer because it known useful several times.

Comment: Thanks @RAM I believe for many people this issue occurs due to the misconfiguration. It's easy to miss out pieces when you are creating the combination for LESS compilation and add minification on top for example.

Comment: also, config section group has to be present in the web.config (if it is missing for some reason):
    `<sectionGroup name="bundleTransformer">
      
<section name="core" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Configuration.CoreSettings, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>`